# Can Result objects be allowed to have behavior?

Tags: java

This is in reference to the [ResultObjectPattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ResultObjectPattern). 
Usually, the ResultObject will be rather simple with just private instance variables referring to various components of the result, and getter methods (possibly setters too?) for those.

Now, would it be a bad idea to add behavior methods to the ResultObject? For example, let's say the ResultObject pushed out one or more of its instance variables to a cache and retrieve them back only when needed, or provided methods that do some computation,-- would that be okay, or would these be things that'd rather be handled by a separate (singleton/utility) class such as a  ResultObjectManager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if behavior is strongly related to data and behavior is not beyond the scope of RO responsibilities - is not bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that when the choice is between adding an instance method to a regular class and adding a static method to anything or any method to a singleton, I'll add the instance method to the regular class.  It's the OO way.